# How to change the className on React Component based on this.click?

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the `className` of an div based on whether it's clicked or not by the user.

```
export default class Dimension extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props)
    this.state ={
      click : false
    }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='scroll-container'>
      <div className={this.state.click ? 'circle-one' : "circle"} id='circle-one'  onClick={() => {
        this.state.click = !this.state.click;
        console.log(this.state.click)
        }}></div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have tried to use constructor, arrow function and even using bind and they always said that they cant read property of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Change how you mutate your state:

```
onClick={() => this.setState({ click: !this.state.click })}
```

**Component**

```
<div
    id='circle-one'
    className={this.state.click ? 'circle-one': 'circle'}
    onClick={() => this.setState({ click: !this.state.click })}>
</div>
```

Also, unless you are maintaining some legacy project, I would highly recommend upgrading your version of React and moving away from class components.

Comment: i want to have 4 divs that change just when they are clicked, if i keep it like that if i click one all of them will change

Comment: should i go for a function component rather than a class component? first i was trying to get it done on a function component but i vthought if i use "this." it wont change all of the cricles color...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to highlight a circle when its clicked? Your question was why your state isnt changing, there are two answers explaining why. Your answer deviates from your initial question

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `this.setState` to change the component's state. If you try to set `this.state.click` directly, the component will not update.

I would also make the event handler callback a method of the component, rather than an in-line arrow/lambda.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Dimension extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { click : false }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      click: !prevState.click
    }))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="scroll-container">
        <div
          id="circle-one"
          className={this.state.click ? 'circle-one' : 'circle'}
          onClick={this.handleClick}></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <Dimension />
);

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
.circle,
.circle-one {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle:hover,
.circle-one:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle-one:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: '1';
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```